# How can I remove all characters before an underscore in multiple filenames at once?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, command-prompt

I have a lot of files in a folder that look like this:

> test_123.txt

> testing_456.txt

> testingagain_789.txt

How can I remove all the characters before and including the underscore across all file names at one time? I've got about 2500 of these files that I need to truncate, but would like to do it in command prompt or powershell if that's possible.

I want them to look like this:

> 123.txt

> 456.txt

> 789.txt

Comment: And what to do with files `test_123.txt`, `testing_123.txt` and `testingagain_123.txt` i.e. if truncated names coincide each other?

Comment: I should have clarified. The numbers at the end of the file names are all unique. They're identifiers. So there shouldn't be any duplicates.

Comment: In a command prompt window run `for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir *_*.txt /A-D /B 2^>nul') do @for /F "eol=| tokens=1* delims=_" %J in ("%~nI") do ren "%I" "%K%~xI"`. Run in same cmd window `for /?` and `dir /?` and `ren /?` to get output the help for these three commands and read them carefully from top of first to bottom of last page to understand the command line.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Path\To\Folder' -File -Filter '*_*.txt'|if ($_.Name -match '^.*?_(.*)') {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $Matches[1]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\Folder' -File 

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Split = $File.Name -split '_'    
    if ($Split.Count -gt 1) {
        Rename-Item -Path $File.FullName -NewName $Split[1]
    }
}
```

Note that there will be exceptions if ever you have name clash (eg: Hello_123.txt, World_123.txt)  but since you mentionned the number were uniques, that should do the trick